# How do I make a regular string array into a const string array after it has been read from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, data-transfer

I have a string array that I am passing from a function into my main, and I would like to change that array into a constant once it is in the main so that the other functions cannot manipulate it. I am not sure how to do this. I am a student and cannot use pointers for this assignment. Here is what I have:

```
//declare variables
string name;
const int size = 11;
string ans[size];
const string corrAns[size] = { "C++","for","if","variable","function", "return",
    "array","void","reference","main", "prototype" };
const string studAns[size];
double percent;

// read file
readFile(name, ans, size);

// calculate percentage
percent = calculatePercentage(corrAns, studAns, size);

// print out report
printReport(name, percent, corrAns, studAns, size);

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

The rest of the program works the way I want it to, however I am not sure how I am supposed to transfer `ans` to `studAns` effectively and have been unsuccessful in finding the answer anywhere.

Comment: Use `const std::string*` as type for the parameters of your functions.

Comment: Why do you think you need to transfer `ans` anywhere as opposed to just using it directly?

Comment: I've spent many years as a professional programmer, and I've never written code to construct a const array in the middle of `main`. You may not use pointers... May you use references?

Comment: I can use references just not pointers. We are just learning pointers and this should use things we have already been introduced to.

Answer (score 1):

> ## How do I make a regular string array into a const string array after it has been read from a file in C++?

You cannot really. What you can do is to prevent changes in subsequent operations by passing a `const std::string*` pointer or a `const std::string[]` array to the functions.

---

However, the idiomatic c++ way would be not to use raw arrays at all, but a `std::vector<std::string>` instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> ans(size);
const std::vector<std::string> corrAns = {   
    "C++","for","if","variable",
    "function", "return",
    "array","void","reference","main", "prototype" };
std::vector<std::string> studAns(size);
```

To prevent functions from changing the values you should have signatures like

```
double calculatePercentage(
    const std::vector<std::string>& corrAns
  , const std::vector<std::string>&  studAns);

void printReport(
    const std::string& name, double percent
  , const std::vector<string>& corrAns
  , const std::vector<string>& studAns);
```

Note that `size` isn't needed, `std::vector` already keeps track of it.

Comment: "You cannot really" A reference to array of const would work fine.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, that doesn't change the constness of the original array, that was what I meant there.

Comment: Yes indeed. It only gives a const view of it to the function it gets passed to. Which I think is good enough for OP, but they haven't been clear enough with their requirements.

Comment: So I am not sure if vectors would be alright to use here or not. We were given three function prototypes to use:                                                    'void readFile(string &, string[], const int);
double calculatePercentage(const string[], const string[], const int);
void printReport(string, double, const string[], const string[], const int);'

Comment: If I take out studAns completely then the array passes fine and the code is good, but I have to have the const string studAns[] according to my professors specifications.

Comment: @MeganMcCracken `const string studAns[]` would be as good as `const string* studAns`. Do you have any particular problems with that?

Comment: The only problem with that is that I am not allowed to use pointers to reallocate the array. Which is most of my dilemma. I have no clue how to transfer the array that I filled from my input file into a const array without a pointer and in the main... As far as what I have read it really can't be done but I wanted to see if I was missing something. If I just read in the ans string array everything in the program works correctly.

Comment: @Megan You're barking up the wrong tree. As mentioned the point is to pass the array as `const` parameters to these functions you're using. Nothing special, you can just declare `const string studAns[]` as a function parameter and pass the non const array.